# AngularJS: How can i solve TypeError: eventService.test is not a function

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-scope

I get this error message when I run my application. I can NOT see what is wrong with my code. I have a simple controller that calls the function in service.js file. And alert message is the lighthouse of, so it means that the code is executed, but then I get TypeError error, why?

**My Controller looks like:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular.module('myApp.EventController', [])

 .controller('EventController', ['$scope', '$http', 'eventService', EventController]);

function EventController($scope,$http, eventService) {

        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.addMode = false;
        $scope.events = [];


        eventService.test().then(function () {
           // $scope.loading = false;
        }, function (error) {
           // $scope.error = "Feilet ved opplasting av event!" + error.data.message;
        });

        $scope.toggleEdit = function () {
            this.event.editMode = !this.event.editMode;
        };

        //by pressing toggleAdd button ng-click in html, this method will be hit
        $scope.toggleAdd = function () {
            $scope.addMode = !$scope.addMode;
        };
    }
```

}());

**Service.js looks like:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module('myApp.eventService', [])

.service('eventService', ['$http', 'ngAuthSettings', eventService]);

function eventService($http, ngAuthSettings) {

    var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;
    alert('ServiceBase: ' + serviceBase)
    this.test = function () {
        alert('Test funker...')
    };
}
```

}());

Comment: I suspect that the error is "evenService.test().then() is not a function." .then is a syntax used with promise. Coul you try to run your code without .then() ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ss5LyCJcxPZ9jUgV9uC9?p=preview Works fine here

Answer (score 0):

You have to return functions declared in your service, then you can call in your controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.eventService');

app.service('eventService', function ($http) {
    return {
        test: function () {
            console.log('Test function');
        },
        //another:function(){}
    }
});
```